# Chrome extension: Como forçar um script a iniciar apenas quando o anterior já terminou?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensão

Tenho uma extnsão que faz a alteração das cores nas imagens das páginas web. 
Quando a extensão é activada (através de um icon na toolbar), as imagens em todas as páginas abertas nos tabs são recoloridas.
Quando o URL de um tab é atualizado, as imagens são então recoloridas também.
Mas, de modo a não mostrar a página original até que a alteração das imagens fique completa, eu escondo o documento (através do "esconde.js").Depois, chamo o "recolor.js", que faz a alterações nas imagens e, por fim o "mostra.js" torna o documento visível.
O problema é que o documento fica visível antes de as imagens estarem recoloridas.
Assim, como posso obrigar a que o script "mostra.js" corra apenas depois de terminar o script "recolor.js"?

Aqui está parte do ficheiro onde os ficheiros script são chamados.

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabid, info, tab) {
 if (flag){
   if (info.status != "complete") 
     chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabid, {file:"esconde.js", runAt: 'document_start' });
   if (info.status == "complete") {
     chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabid, {file:"recolor.js", runAt: 'document_start' });
     chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabid, {file:"mostra.js", runAt: 'document_start' });
     chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "off.png", tabId:tab.id});
   }
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Segundo [a documentação](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript), o método `executeScript` aceita como terceiro parâmetro um *callback* que executa quando o script terminar. Portanto você pode fazer assim:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabid, info, tab) {
  if (flag){
    if (info.status != "complete") 
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabid, {file:"esconde.js", runAt: 'document_start' });
    if (info.status == "complete") {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabid, {file:"recolor.js", runAt: 'document_start' }, function() {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabid, {file:"mostra.js", runAt: 'document_start' });
      });
      chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "off.png", tabId:tab.id});
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Obrigada pela sugestão, mas ainda não funciona. Ainda se veem as imagens originais primeiro.

Comment: Então deve ter alguma operação assíncrona ocorrendo no arquivo recolor.js. Tem como postar o conteúdo desse arquivo? Se for grande, melhor colocar em algum serviço externo e postar o link.

Comment: Obrigada pela disponibilidade. O meu e-mail é m70ribeiro@gmail.com. Se quiser, enviar-me um email, eu envio a extensão completa zipada. Obrigada